# Angular2/4. Can I bind a function to ngModel?

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using ngbDatePicker from the ng-bootstrap. I am trying to set a default date which is returned from an API. This doesn't seem to work as either i get errors or the browser freezes. The code snippet looks like this

`<input class="form-control" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" name="from" [ngModel]="formatDate(filter.nodes[0])" (ngModelChange)="filter.nodes[0] = updateDate($event)" ngbDatepicker #d1="ngbDatepicker">`

filter.nodes[0] is the date value that is returned from the API as a string. I need to format this into a JS Object for it to bind to the input.

Comment: Check if exist filter.nodes: `[ngModel]="filter?.nodes?formatDate(filter.nodes[0]):null" (ngModelChange)="filter?.nodes && filter.nodes[0] = updateDate($event)"`

Answer (score 6):

You may use `(ngModelChange)="yourMethod($event)"` to bind ngModel to a method

```
<input label="Choose a year" (ngModelChange)="selectYearGraph($event)" [(ngModel)]="chosenYearDate" ></input>
```

then in your ts file

```
yourMethod($event){
//do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting data from API , then don't use  dot notation. Because while loading DOM you don't have 'node' property in 'filter' variable. 
So try using filter['node'][0] and additionally you can also check that input field will show after loading data from API. In your case, you can try this.

```
<input *ngIf="filter['nodes'] && filter['nodes'][0]" class="form-control" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" name="from" [ngModel]="formatDate(filter['nodes'][0])" (ngModelChange)="filter['nodes'][0] = updateDate($event)" ngbDatepicker #d1="ngbDatepicker">
```

Let me know is it working or not.

Comment: ngbDatePicker need an Object with year, month and day. It's not possible that you feed the model with a string. You need , in anywhere make some like: let datesteps=filter.nodes[0].split('-');fecha={year:parseInt(datesteps[0]),month:parseInt(datesteps[1]),day:parseInt(datestep[2])}  and make the ngModel about fecha

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable to update the ngmodel and change the modal in the function

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" name="from" [ngModel]="dateData" (change)="updateDate($event)" ngbDatepicker #d1="ngbDatepicker">
```

In Ts file:-

```
dateData:any;
 ngOnit(){
  //call the api and write below on success response block
  this.dateData = this.formatDate(this.filter.nodes[0]);
  // Sets the initial date value
 }
  updateDate($event){
  //update your date here
     let date = logictoGetDate($event);
     this.dateData=this.formatDate(date); //
  }
```